# How to modify a string inside a serde_json::Value::String?

Tags: json, rust, serde, serde-json

I have a [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html) containing a string that I want to modify, if possible without cloning the string. I would imagine you would do it like this:

```
let mut value = Value::String("Hello world".to_string());
let mut string = value.as_mut_string().unwrap();
string.push('!');
```

But there is no such thing as `as_mut_string`. I could do this:

```
let mut value = Value::String("Hello world".to_string());
let mut string = value.as_str().unwrap().to_string();
string.push('!');
value = Value::String(string);
```

However, this is both ugly code and inefficient since I have to clone the string. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`serde_json::value::Value` is an `enum`, you can just pattern match it:

```
let mut value = Value::String("Hello world".to_string());
if let Value::String(string) = &mut value {
    string.push('!');
}

println!("{:?}", value);
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a8d5418cef1be3c58f8b9142555c2056))